# How to parse the Xcode version as returned by the -showBuildSettings flag in xcodebuild?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

On a directory that holds an Xcode project, you can run

`xcodebuild -showBuildSettings`

to get a list of build settings. A few of them relate to the Xcode ver

```
XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL = 0940
XCODE_VERSION_MAJOR = 0900
XCODE_VERSION_MINOR = 0940
```

What's the proper way to parse them to get the Xcode version?

e.g. in the case above, that should be 9.4

## Update

Just to clarify, I'm asking how to interpret the 0940. Not how to do the operation from bash.

e.g.
0940 = 9.4
1000 = 10.0

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Unix expert, but I believe you need to pipe this command to `awk` and then extract it and transform it to the format you want.

Something like this might be appropriate:

`xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | awk -F= '/XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL/{x=$NF; gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",x); print int(x)/100}'`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I literally meant how to parse the 0940 number. Not how to do it from bash. So, are you saying that dividing by 100 is the way to do it? How about 1000/100 which leads to 10, rather than 10.0?

Comment: Well that depends on the language I suppose. Generally you want to convert the "0940" string to a float and then divide it by 100.0 so you will always get a float number in the end.